# Just moved Laravel project to a new server, but JSON could not be serialized

Tags: php, json, laravel, api

I'm a website owner, and a novice Laravel Programmer.
I've received the Laravel website (hosted on Hostgator shared hosting) with linked mobile native applications (Android and iOS versions), but after more users have used the app, i had to move to a VPS plan with Hostinger.

I've succeeded to migrate the whole laravel project, and the Laravel login, dashboard and databases are working fine, but the problem is that the Mobile applications can't authorize or receive data from the database!

When trying to sign into iOS application gives a message: " Json could not be serialized because of error: The data couldn't be read because it isn't in the correct format."

When trying to sign into Android application gives a message: "Login Failed ...!"

I've tried to see the Laravel log, but no error was reported.

Do not know where the problem is or where to start?
Can you please help

Comment: Is the server returning `Content-Type: application/json` in the response headers?

Comment: Exuse me, but how can i check for that?

Comment: Try to enable Laravel log and check errors.

Comment: Laravel logs are enabled, but this error does not appear in the staorage/Laravel.log.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. It's just prefix to differ my api routes from other routes.

In app\Providers\RouteServiceProvider, I have changed function mapApiRoutes()